# How to write rspec for a model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Here's my method

```
def get_processing_fee_for_given_price(ticket_service_fee, price)
    ((processing_fee_percent / 100.0) * (ticket_service_fee.to_f + price.to_f))
  end
```

I want to write rspec for this method.

```
def processing_fee_percent
    3.0
  end
```

This is my processing_fee_percent method

Comment: That's a pretty straight forward method to test. Set `processing_fee_percent` on the object, call the method, check it returns the correct value. Are you having a specific problem writing the test? Could you show us what you've tried, please?

Comment: Yeah, I can't build up the logic on how to write it. I am new to rspec @Schwern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
describe '#get_processing_fee_for_given_price' do
  subject(:instance) { described_class.new } 

  it 'returns to expected processing_fee' do
    expect(
      instance.get_processing_fee_for_given_price(5, 100)
    ).to eq 3.15
  end
end
```

There are [accuracy problems when using floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), therefore it is not recommended to use floats for currency calculations. A very simple example of unexpected behavior with floats is this one:

```
0.1 + 0.2
#=> 0.30000000000000004
```

I suggest using [`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: My processing fee percent is 3.0 for all calculation. Like if my price is 100 and service fee is 5 then my processing fee should be (100+5)*3/100.

Comment: and processing fee percent is also a method in the model

Comment: Then please share what the `processing_fee_percent` method looks like. How is it calculated? How can it be set?

Comment: @testuser I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @spickermann. Now I can do it.